# Validating a html form using javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

In my html form i have different elements, textbox,radio boxes & select boxes.
When I submit this form i want to validate it (just textboxes are empty,radio boxes are checked ,select boxes are selected )
Can all these elements be validated at once .
No matter if it can be done using jquery?
Can anyone suggest me a way?

Comment: What have you tried? This can be easily done with a few lines of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If JQuery is an option:

```
$('#submitbuttonid').submit(function() {  
    //validate as many things as you want here.  
    //If everything is valid, you can 'return true;'  else 'return false;'  
});
```

Replace #submitbuttonid with the id of your submit button.  Take a look here, for more discussion: http://api.jquery.com/submit/